# Setting and getting models by CID in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have this collection:

```
App.Collection.Pieces = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: App.Model.Piece,
  initialize: function() {
    this.add(
      // The `King` model extends the `Piece` model
      new App.Model.King({
        cid: 'wk',
        color: 'white'
      })
    );
  }
});
```

Then I have this code in a view:

```
this.white = new App.Collection.Pieces();
console.log(this.white.get('wk'));
```

I have two questions:

1. Can I add a model `B` to a collection of `A` models, if `B` extends `A`?
2. The `console.log` statement returns undefined. Any reason why the `cid` property is not being set?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add any object or model to a collection. If its a plain JS object, the model defined for the collection will be instantiated. [Annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-81)
2. According to [Backbone's documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid) the cid is automatically assigned to all models created. Looking at [the annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-28) it seems the cid is automatically generated - you cannot assign a custom cid to a model.